# namedParameterJdbctemplate update with more than one fields to update

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

Trying to update multiple column values in a table.
What I am missing, a little help!

The `dao` method is like...
The `dao` class *Plan* has all the fields populated with appropriate data.

```
 public void updatePlan(Plan plan) {
    SqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("id", plan.getId())
            .addValue("plan_name", plan.getPlan())
            .addValue("price_category", plan.getPrice_category())
            .addValue("updated_by", subscriptionPlan.getId());

    String UPDATE_PLAN = "UPDATE plan_table SET(plan_name= :plan_name, price_category= :price_category, updated_by= :id) where id=:id)";

    SqlParameterSource parameterSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(subscriptionPlan);
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_PLAN, mapSqlParameterSource);
}
```

The error is...(MySQL database - 5.6.43, Workbench - 6.3.9)

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>
> PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [update webstat_plan set (plan_name= ?, price_category= ?, updated_by= ?) where id=?)]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax....

Comment: Have you tried to execute the SQL statement (of course with real values instead of placeholder)? This could help to find syntax issues.

Comment: thanks....for the suggestion. helped. It's so silly of me. Though the bracket after SET is not required per say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with your SQL Query.
Parenthesis is not required while updating the table.

Update your query with

**UPDATE plan_table SET plan_name= :plan_name, price_category= :price_category, updated_by= :id where id=:id**

Comment: What is the error log , please format and improve you question if you wanna help from somebody.